# Custom protocol handlers in Sonoma

Tags: applescript, calendar, script, sonoma

I want to be able to insert hyperlinks into Calendar entries, such that when I click them, then the command

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/emacsclient -n --eval '(org-open-link-from-string \"" & address & "\")'
```

is executed, where `address` is the URL of the link.

Before the update to Sonoma, this worked fine, with the following Apple Script:

```
on open location this_URL
    set len to length of this_URL
    set prefixlen to length of "mu4e://"
    set address to characters (prefixlen + 1) thru len of this_URL as string
    do shell script "/opt/homebrew/bin/emacsclient -n --eval '(org-open-link-from-string \"" & address & "\")'"
    tell application "Emacs" to activate
end open location
```

I have exported this script as an .app, and then changed the `Info.plist` file by adding

```
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myown.AppleScript.mu4e</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>mu4e</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>mu4e</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

and then running the application one, to register the app as the handler for the `mu4e://` protocol.

In Sonoma, this does not work anymore. When I proceed as above, then insert a link into an app such as Calendar, and then click it, then my app is run (it shows very briefly in the dock, then disappears), but nothing else happens.

It might be that my app is prevented from running emacsclient via the the shell script. But I do not get any error message, or a pop up asking whether my app is able to control emacsclient.

Thank you very much in advance for any advice on enabling custom protocol handlers in Sonoma!